# HttpWebRequest. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, internal-server-error

I need help with HttpWebRequest in C#. Below lines of codes are working fine for local IIS but when I upload to remote server, it starts to giving me "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.". I have try many variations with GET and POST method but unable to figure it out what is the problem. Please have a look into below code and let me know what is wrong with this.

```
try
{
    string postData = "applicaitonid=abc&deviceid=xyz";
    string uri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("baseUrl") + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ABApiPath") + "ConfirmAppBinding/?" + postData;

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST"; // Set type Post
    //request.Method = "GET";
    request.UserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString();
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    request.MediaType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    //byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(postData);
    request.Timeout = 500000;             //Increase timeout for testing

    Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
    //reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    reqstr.Close();

    // Read Response
    var httpResponse = request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JsonMessage.message = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    JsonMessage.message = e.Message;
    return Json(JsonMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As I told you, I have used default GET method but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The problem is on the server side.

Comment: Have you looked at the response body in the exception? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/c-sharp-webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body.

Answer (score 18):

Use this code for catch

```
catch (WebException e)
{
   string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
   return pageContent;
}
```

It'll show the exact error you are facing.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me figure out that i had the `[ValidateAntiyForgeryToken]` on my controller denying me my request  from the error.

Comment: Thank you !! this helped me to figure out the issue...

Answer (score 4):

You can use try and catch block to find the root cause.

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    string message = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i will take a stab in the dark

Could it be you have a spelling mistake in your querystring and when reference the key in code it comes back with a nullvalue exception ?

```
{ String postData = "applicaitonid=abc&deviceid=xyz"; 
}
```

should be

```
{ String postData = "applicationid=abc&deviceid=xyz";  }
```

Comment: Ignore spelling mistake in query string. Its typo in here. Code is working fine in locally. But when I publish it to remote server then its giving "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error".

Comment: There are a lot of "Variables", how about your uri value? does the abapipath directory exist on the remote server ?

Comment: @Wombelite I indeed was hitting same issue. Instead of `userId`, I was using 'userID'. Thanks.