# web api returns a json error but visual studio only sees it as status code 500

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting a 500 status code back in visual studio for an api shown below although when using PostMan with the same credentials I get a json response back saying the token has expired.  Is this because I'm not seeing the response back as json or something?  Obviously I need to handle if the token has expired so getting 500 back is not sufficient.  Many thanks,

**Code failing with status code 500**

[image]

**Same call but using PostMan**

[image]

Comment: the two calls must be different. dont second guess, use fiddler to log the requests and compare them.

Comment: its the same.  If you look at postman screen shot, the status is 500  as well but I'm not sure how to access the body to check the error_code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body

Comment: yeah I was looking at that as well.  It turns out its the webexception that needs to be used, rather than generic exception object.  thanks,

Answer (score 0):

use WebException rather than Exception.