# Read source code of 404 page using WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a site that returns a custom 404 page, I need to get the source code of it and determine what kind of 404 it's returning. Is there a way to get the source code of the 404 page?

```
try
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
        webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(file.Address), file.SaveLocation);
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    // read source code here...
}
```

Comment: `404` means the end point was not found. Not sure how you want to read the source of something that does not exist.

Comment: 404 can return a custom error page, the error code (status code) means the file isn't found, not the page necessarily.

Comment: Do you want to get the "page", as in the 404 page? Literally meaning, the page that your server provides given a "not found" error? Why not just open it in the browse and hit "view source" out of the context menu? Or if you're on Linux, use curl or wget?

Comment: I need to do this in C# for a generic URL. I need to get the content of the page, the 404 error page.

Comment: The MSDN page says that WebException has a Response and Source property (Nope, "source" is not "source code" in this case). Maybe one of those is what you're looking for? Have you tried either one of them? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you mean by 404 page a "soft 404' page? such as this one? https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/ ,i.e. it returns a page content with 404 header.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution (tested), which in all fairness @KamilJarosz hinted in a comment to your question:

```
...
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Response != null && (e.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        var Html404Page = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }
}
```

Of course I thought you wanted a string, so I adapted the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body).

**EDIT**

I also added a guard clause, to prevent further problems if the Response is null and processing if the response is not a 404 one.

Comment: What if the response is null?

Comment: @chaotic AFAIK it might be if the exception is not related to a 404 but to a previous error, e.g. if `file.SaveLocation` is not a complete path, of if the URL you provided cannot be resolved. Why are you asking?

Comment: @chaotic I updated my answer to take that into account too.