# Public member 'error' on type 'JObject' not found

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I'm trying to catch the error message from a `WebRequest` that returns a 400 Bad Request message when the user enters bad info. I want to display the message to the screen and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body), I should be able to deserialize the string containing the JSON and then access the error message like this:

```
    Try
        'My web request is here
    Catch ex As WebException            
        Using resp As HttpWebResponse = ex.Response
            Using data As Stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader = New StreamReader(data)

                    Dim bodyContent As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    Dim bodyObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyContent)

                    lblMyLabel.Text = bodyObj.error.message
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Try
```

However, I'm getting an error message saying:

> Public member 'error' on type 'JObject' not found.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JObject class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) does not have an `error` property or method. Assuming that your JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "...",
    "status": "...",
    "...": "..."
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

Then you would use:

```
lblMyLabel.Text = bodyObj("error")("message").ToString()
```

However, you should provide an example of what the response looks like so that I can provide an exact example.